# Is it possible to concatenate 2 arrays together within an IF formula or Countif formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

E.g. I want to check if array (B1:B10) concatenated with (C1:C10) contains the text in cell A1, and if it does, return "Detected".

Some background info:
1) When those 2 arrays are concatenated together, they should have same length as A1. 
2) Arrays concatenated with equivalent range value e.g. B1 with C1, B2 with C2.

*EDIT*

Using BigBen's template below, I tried =IF((MATCH(LEFT(A1,3),B1:B10,0)=MATCH(RIGHT(A1,3),C1:C10,0)),"detected","")
and managed to get the desired result; however, it does not account for duplicates 'bar' within column C.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wynrF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gioKm.png)

Comment: Are you planning to use Excel VBA on this?

Comment: This sounds like you might have gotten a x-y problem to me. Why do you have concatenated value in A1 in the first place? Why not a multi criteria search.

Comment: I might use it on VBA later on; but for now just excel.

@JvdV could you elaborate on what you mean by multi criteria search? A1 is a unique serial number basically; which is unique only when concatenating values

Comment: Basically what I see more often is that actually your ID isn't `foobar` but `foo` and `bar` put together to make matching values "easy" by concatenating two columns. However, concatenating columns is considered poor practice. Imagine your data, and what if it contains in `B` > `foob` and in `C` > `ar`. Now concatenating the two columns could result into unexpected and unwanted results. Instead check each column seperately. Perhaps in your case you get by. But you can imagine that won't always be the case. That's why I mentioned it.

Comment: I see what you mean now, but i don't think i would run into this problem considering columns B & C actually contains port codes which are always 5 lettered. Guess i should've mentioned that earlier

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use MATCH for this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,B1:B10&C1:C10,0)),"Detected","")
```

[image]

**IMPORTANT:** Note that depending on your version of Excel, you may need to enter the formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: =MATCH(A1,B1:B10&C1:C10) doesn't return any value

Comment: You forgot the `,0` for exact match. Would also help if you edited your question with some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: I tried replicating your sheet but can't seem to get the 'detected' result. Regarding sample data, i think you pretty much understood me completely.

Comment: Ahhhh... mine works as is because I have the new Excel Dynamic Arrays... enter the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: that works like a charm! I just posted my 2nd ineffectual attempt seconds ago, do you mind explaining what purpose 'isnumber' serves here?

Comment: MATCH returns a number if it is successful, otherwise it returns an error. So if the result is a number, there is a match.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably *very* brittle, but given the data outline in BigBen's answer, this array formula (needs to be confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter) returns the expected result:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,B1:B10&C1:C10),1)),"Detected","")
```

It basically joins each value in column B with the corresponding value in column C, then checks to see if the key word is detected in the resulting string.  It is also dependant on you having a version of Excel that has the TEXTJOIN function.

Here is a view of the formula evaluation:
[image: Screen grab of formula]

*note, I trimmed the data down to only 5 records, but you get it...